# In R, decompose() function returning error message

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following code below:

```
temp.ts <- xts(df$Temp, order.by = seq(as.POSIXct("2017-05-31 17:02:30"), length=18596, by="min"))
periodicity(temp.ts) #returns 1 minute
x=as.ts(temp.ts)
results = decompose(x)
```

The temperature data are from 2017-05-31T17:02:30.000Z to 2017-06-13T14:57:30.000Z. Even though my data seem to be more than 2 periods, I still get the error message "Error in decompose(x) : time series has no or less than 2 periods".

Comment: Show what library you're using; `xts` isn't part of base R.

Comment: Show us some output of your debugging efforts.

Comment: Sorry, library is "xts".

Comment: So my debugging efforts are in the code above. Initially I thought the problem was with the periodicity, so I double checked that. Then I thought maybe it's because decompose() doesn't work on the xts object, as stated here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744218/set-frequency-in-xts-object

So I converted it to ts object, but it still doesn't work. I'm out of ideas. N.B: It gave the same error message for each debugging effort.