# How to do a partial autocorrelation plot with many zeros in r

Tags: r, time-series, lag, zoo

I have a dataset of ER admissions with many zeros. These are daily admissions from `2016-06-05` to `2019-12-31`. This is my data:

```
df<-structure(list(date = structure(c(1465084800, 1465171200, 1465257600, 
1465344000, 1465430400, 1465516800, 1465603200, 1465689600, 1465776000, 
1465862400, 1465948800, 1466035200, 1466121600, 1466208000, 1466294400, 
1466380800, 1466467200, 1466553600, 1466640000, 1466726400, 1466812800, 
1466899200, 1466985600, 1467072000, 1467158400, 1467244800, 1467331200, 
1467417600, 1467504000, 1467590400, 1467676800, 1467763200, 1467849600, 
1467936000, 1468022400, 1468108800, 1468195200, 1468281600, 1468368000, 
1468454400, 1468540800, 1468627200, 1468713600, 1468800000, 1468886400, 
1468972800, 1469059200, 1469145600, 1469232000, 1469318400, 1469404800, 
1469491200, 1469577600, 1469664000, 1469750400, 1469836800, 1469923200, 
1470009600, 1470096000, 1470182400, 1470268800, 1470355200, 1470441600, 
1470528000, 1470614400, 1470700800, 1470787200, 1470873600, 1470960000, 
1471046400, 1471132800, 1471219200, 1471305600, 1471392000, 1471478400, 
1471564800, 1471651200, 1471737600, 1471824000, 1471910400, 1471996800, 
1472083200, 1472169600, 1472256000, 1472342400, 1472428800, 1472515200, 
1472601600, 1472688000, 1472774400, 1472860800, 1472947200, 1473033600, 
1473120000, 1473206400, 1473292800, 1473379200, 1473465600, 1473552000, 
1473638400, 1473724800, 1473811200, 1473897600, 1473984000, 1474070400, 
1474156800, 1474243200, 1474329600, 1474416000, 1474502400, 1474588800, 
1474675200, 1474761600, 1474848000, 1474934400, 1475020800, 1475107200, 
1475193600, 1475280000, 1475366400, 1475452800, 1475539200, 1475625600, 
1475712000, 1475798400, 1475884800, 1475971200, 1476057600, 1476144000, 
1476230400, 1476316800, 1476403200, 1476489600, 1476576000, 1476662400, 
1476748800, 1476835200, 1476921600, 1477008000, 1477094400, 1477180800, 
1477267200, 1477353600, 1477440000, 1477526400, 1477612800, 1477699200, 
1477785600, 1477872000, 1477958400, 1478044800, 1478131200, 1478217600, 
1478304000, 1478390400, 1478476800, 1478563200, 1478649600, 1478736000, 
1478822400, 1478908800, 1478995200, 1479081600, 1479168000, 1479254400, 
1479340800, 1479427200, 1479513600, 1479600000, 1479686400, 1479772800, 
1479859200, 1479945600, 1480032000, 1480118400, 1480204800, 1480291200, 
1480377600, 1480464000, 1480550400, 1480636800, 1480723200, 1480809600, 
1480896000, 1480982400, 1481068800, 1481155200, 1481241600, 1481328000, 
1481414400, 1481500800, 1481587200, 1481673600, 1481760000, 1481846400, 
1481932800, 1482019200, 1482105600, 1482192000, 1482278400, 1482364800, 
1482451200, 1482537600, 1482624000, 1482710400, 1482796800, 1482883200, 
1482969600, 1483056000, 1483142400, 1483228800, 1483315200, 1483401600, 
1483488000, 1483574400, 1483660800, 1483747200, 1483833600, 1483920000, 
1484006400, 1484092800, 1484179200, 1484352000, 1484438400, 1484524800, 
1484611200, 1484697600, 1484784000, 1484870400, 1484956800, 1485043200, 
1485129600, 1485216000, 1485302400, 1485388800, 1485475200, 1485561600, 
1485648000, 1485734400, 1485820800, 1485907200, 1485993600, 1486080000, 
1486166400, 1486252800, 1486339200, 1486425600, 1486512000, 1486598400, 
1486684800, 1486771200, 1486857600, 1486944000, 1487030400, 1487116800, 
1487203200, 1487289600, 1487376000, 1487462400, 1487548800, 1487635200, 
1487721600, 1487808000, 1487894400, 1487980800, 1488067200, 1488153600, 
1488240000, 1488326400, 1488412800, 1488499200, 1488585600, 1488672000, 
1488758400, 1488844800, 1488931200, 1489017600, 1489104000, 1489190400, 
1489276800, 1489363200, 1489449600, 1489536000, 1489622400, 1489708800, 
1489795200, 1489881600, 1489968000, 1490054400, 1490140800, 1490227200, 
1490313600, 1490400000, 1490486400, 1490572800, 1490659200, 1490745600, 
1490832000, 1490918400, 1491004800, 1491091200, 1491177600, 1491264000, 
1491350400, 1491436800, 1491523200, 1491609600, 1491696000, 1491782400,
1491868800, 1491955200, 1492041600, 1492128000, 1492214400, 1492300800, 
1492387200, 1492473600, 1492560000, 1492646400, 1492732800, 1492819200, 
1492905600, 1492992000, 1493078400, 1493164800, 1493251200, 1493337600, 
1493424000, 1493510400, 1493596800, 1493683200, 1493769600, 1493856000, 
1493942400, 1494028800, 1494115200, 1494201600, 1494288000, 1494374400, 
1494460800, 1494547200, 1494633600, 1494720000, 1494806400, 1494892800, 
1494979200, 1495065600, 1495152000, 1495238400, 1495324800, 1495411200, 
1495497600, 1495584000, 1495670400, 1495756800, 1495843200, 1495929600, 
1496016000, 1496102400, 1496188800, 1496275200, 1496361600, 1496448000, 
1496534400, 1496620800, 1496707200, 1496793600, 1496880000, 1496966400, 
1497052800, 1497139200, 1497225600, 1497312000, 1497398400, 1497484800, 
1497571200, 1497657600, 1497744000, 1497830400, 1497916800, 1498003200, 
1498089600, 1498176000, 1498262400, 1498348800, 1498435200, 1498521600, 
1498608000, 1498694400, 1498780800, 1498867200, 1498953600, 1499040000, 
1499126400, 1499212800, 1499299200, 1499385600, 1499472000, 1499558400, 
1499644800, 1499731200, 1499817600, 1499904000, 1499990400, 1500076800, 
1500163200, 1500249600, 1500336000, 1500422400, 1500508800, 1500595200, 
1500681600, 1500768000, 1500854400, 1500940800, 1501027200, 1501113600, 
1501200000, 1501286400, 1501372800, 1501459200, 1501545600, 1501632000, 
1501718400, 1501804800, 1501891200, 1501977600, 1502064000, 1502150400, 
1502236800, 1502323200, 1502409600, 1502496000, 1502582400, 1502668800, 
1502755200, 1502841600, 1502928000, 1503014400, 1503100800, 1503187200, 
1503273600, 1503360000, 1503446400, 1503532800, 1503619200, 1503705600, 
1503792000, 1503878400, 1503964800, 1504051200, 1504137600, 1504224000, 
1504310400, 1504396800, 1504483200, 1504569600, 1504656000, 1504742400, 
1504828800, 1504915200, 1505001600, 1505088000, 1505174400, 1505260800, 
1505347200, 1505433600, 1505520000, 1505606400, 1505692800, 1505779200, 
1505865600, 1505952000, 1506038400, 1506124800, 1506211200, 1506297600, 
1506384000, 1506470400, 1506556800, 1506643200, 1506729600, 1506816000, 
1506902400, 1506988800, 1507075200, 1507161600, 1507248000, 1507334400, 
1507420800, 1507507200, 1507593600, 1507680000, 1507766400, 1507852800, 
1507939200, 1508025600, 1508112000, 1508198400, 1508284800, 1508371200, 
1508457600, 1508544000, 1508630400, 1508716800, 1508803200, 1508889600, 
1508976000, 1509062400, 1509148800, 1509235200, 1509321600, 1509408000, 
1509494400, 1509580800, 1509667200, 1509753600, 1509840000, 1509926400, 
1510012800, 1510099200, 1510185600, 1510272000, 1510358400, 1510444800, 
1510531200, 1510617600, 1510704000, 1510790400, 1510876800, 1510963200, 
1511049600, 1511136000, 1511222400, 1511308800, 1511395200, 1511481600, 
1511568000, 1511654400, 1511740800, 1511827200, 1511913600, 1.512e+09, 
1512086400, 1512172800, 1512259200, 1512345600, 1512432000, 1512518400, 
1512604800, 1512691200, 1512777600, 1512864000, 1512950400, 1513036800, 
1513123200, 1513209600, 1513296000, 1513382400, 1513468800, 1513555200, 
1513641600, 1513728000, 1513814400, 1513900800, 1513987200, 1514073600, 
1514160000, 1514246400, 1514332800, 1514419200, 1514505600, 1514592000, 
1514678400, 1514764800, 1514851200, 1514937600, 1515024000, 1515110400, 
1515196800, 1515283200, 1515369600, 1515456000, 1515542400, 1515628800, 
1515715200, 1515801600, 1515888000, 1515974400, 1516060800, 1516147200, 
1516233600, 1516320000, 1516406400, 1516492800, 1516579200, 1516665600, 
1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800, 1517011200, 1517097600, 1517184000, 
1517270400, 1517356800, 1517443200, 1517529600, 1517616000, 1517702400, 
1517788800, 1517875200, 1517961600, 1518048000, 1518134400, 1518220800, 
1518307200, 1518393600, 1518480000, 1518566400, 1518652800, 1518739200, 
1518825600, 1518912000, 1518998400, 1519084800, 1519171200, 1519257600, 
1519344000, 1519430400, 1519516800, 1519603200, 1519689600, 1519776000, 
1519862400, 1519948800, 1520035200, 1520121600, 1520208000, 1520294400, 
1520380800, 1520467200, 1520553600, 1520640000, 1520726400, 1520812800, 
1520899200, 1520985600, 1521072000, 1521158400, 1521244800, 1521331200, 
1521417600, 1521504000, 1521590400, 1521676800, 1521763200, 1521849600, 
1521936000, 1522022400, 1522108800, 1522195200, 1522281600, 1522368000, 
1522454400, 1522540800, 1522627200, 1522713600, 1522800000, 1522886400, 
1522972800, 1523059200, 1523145600, 1523232000, 1523318400, 1523404800, 
1523491200, 1523577600, 1523664000, 1523750400, 1523836800, 1523923200, 
1524009600, 1524096000, 1524182400, 1524268800, 1524355200, 1524441600, 
1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 1524787200, 1524873600, 1524960000, 
1525046400, 1525132800, 1525219200, 1525305600, 1525392000, 1525478400, 
1525564800, 1525651200, 1525737600, 1525824000, 1525910400, 1525996800, 
1526083200, 1526169600, 1526256000, 1526342400, 1526428800, 1526515200, 
1526601600, 1526688000, 1526774400, 1526860800, 1526947200, 1527033600, 
1527120000, 1527206400, 1527292800, 1527379200, 1527465600, 1527552000, 
1527638400, 1527724800, 1527811200, 1527897600, 1527984000, 1528070400, 
1528156800, 1528243200, 1528329600, 1528416000, 1528502400, 1528588800, 
1528675200, 1528761600, 1528848000, 1528934400, 1529020800, 1529107200, 
1529193600, 1529280000, 1529366400, 1529452800, 1529539200, 1529625600, 
1529712000, 1529798400, 1529884800, 1529971200, 1530057600, 1530144000, 
1530230400, 1530316800, 1530403200, 1530489600, 1530576000, 1530662400, 
1530748800, 1530835200, 1530921600, 1531008000, 1531094400, 1531180800, 
1531267200, 1531353600, 1531440000, 1531526400, 1531612800, 1531699200, 
1531785600, 1531872000, 1531958400, 1532044800, 1532131200, 1532217600, 
1532304000, 1532390400, 1532476800, 1532563200, 1532649600, 1532736000, 
1532822400, 1532908800, 1532995200, 1533081600, 1533168000, 1533254400, 
1533340800, 1533427200, 1533513600, 1533600000, 1533686400, 1533772800, 
1533859200, 1533945600, 1534032000, 1534118400, 1534204800, 1534291200, 
1534377600, 1534464000, 1534550400, 1534636800, 1534723200, 1534809600, 
1534896000, 1534982400, 1535068800, 1535155200, 1535241600, 1535328000, 
1535414400, 1535500800, 1535587200, 1535673600, 1535760000, 1535846400, 
1535932800, 1536019200, 1536105600, 1536192000, 1536278400, 1536364800, 
1536451200, 1536537600, 1536624000, 1536710400, 1536796800, 1536883200, 
1536969600, 1537056000, 1537142400, 1537228800, 1537315200, 1537401600, 
1537488000, 1537574400, 1537660800, 1537747200, 1537833600, 1537920000, 
1538006400, 1538092800, 1538179200, 1538265600, 1538352000, 1538438400, 
1538524800, 1538611200, 1538697600, 1538784000, 1538870400, 1538956800, 
1539043200, 1539129600, 1539216000, 1539302400, 1539388800, 1539475200, 
1539561600, 1539648000, 1539734400, 1539820800, 1539907200, 1539993600, 
1540080000, 1540166400, 1540252800, 1540339200, 1540425600, 1540512000, 
1540598400, 1540684800, 1540771200, 1540857600, 1540944000, 1541030400, 
1541116800, 1541203200, 1541289600, 1541376000, 1541462400, 1541548800, 
1541635200, 1541721600, 1541808000, 1541894400, 1541980800, 1542067200, 
1542153600, 1542240000, 1542326400, 1542412800, 1542499200, 1542585600, 
1542672000, 1542758400, 1542844800, 1542931200, 1543017600, 1543104000, 
1543190400, 1543276800, 1543363200, 1543449600, 1543536000, 1543622400, 
1543708800, 1543795200, 1543881600, 1543968000, 1544054400, 1544140800, 
1544227200, 1544313600, 1544400000, 1544486400, 1544572800, 1544659200, 
1544745600, 1544832000, 1544918400, 1545004800, 1545091200, 1545177600, 
1545264000, 1545350400, 1545436800, 1545523200, 1545609600, 1545696000, 
1545782400, 1545868800, 1545955200, 1546041600, 1546128000, 1546214400, 
1546300800, 1546387200, 1546473600, 1546560000, 1546646400, 1546732800, 
1546819200, 1546905600, 1546992000, 1547078400, 1547164800, 1547251200, 
1547337600, 1547424000, 1547510400, 1547596800, 1547683200, 1547769600, 
1547856000, 1547942400, 1548028800, 1548115200, 1548201600, 1548288000, 
1548374400, 1548460800, 1548547200, 1548633600, 1548720000, 1548806400, 
1548892800, 1548979200, 1549065600, 1549152000, 1549238400, 1549324800, 
1549411200, 1549497600, 1549584000, 1549670400, 1549756800, 1549843200, 
1549929600, 1550016000, 1550102400, 1550188800, 1550275200, 1550361600, 
1550448000, 1550534400, 1550620800, 1550707200, 1550793600, 1550880000, 
1550966400, 1551052800, 1551139200, 1551225600, 1551312000, 1551398400, 
1551484800, 1551571200, 1551657600, 1551744000, 1551830400, 1551916800, 
1552003200, 1552089600, 1552176000, 1552262400, 1552348800, 1552435200, 
1552521600, 1552608000, 1552694400, 1552780800, 1552867200, 1552953600, 
1553040000, 1553126400, 1553212800, 1553299200, 1553385600, 1553472000, 
1553558400, 1553644800, 1553731200, 1553817600, 1553904000, 1553990400, 
1554076800, 1554163200, 1554249600, 1554336000, 1554422400, 1554508800, 
1554595200, 1554681600, 1554768000, 1554854400, 1554940800, 1555027200, 
1555113600, 1555200000, 1555286400, 1555372800, 1555459200, 1555545600, 
1555632000, 1555718400, 1555804800, 1555891200, 1555977600, 1556064000, 
1556150400, 1556236800, 1556323200, 1556409600, 1556496000, 1556582400, 
1556668800, 1556755200, 1556841600, 1556928000, 1557014400, 1557100800, 
1557187200, 1557273600, 1557360000, 1557446400, 1557532800, 1557619200, 
1557705600, 1557792000, 1557878400, 1557964800, 1558051200, 1558137600, 
1558224000, 1558310400, 1558396800, 1558483200, 1558569600, 1558656000, 
1558742400, 1558828800, 1558915200, 1559001600, 1559088000, 1559174400, 
1559260800, 1559347200, 1559433600, 1559520000, 1559606400, 1559692800, 
1559779200, 1559865600, 1559952000, 1560038400, 1560124800, 1560211200, 
1560297600, 1560384000, 1560470400, 1560556800, 1560643200, 1560729600, 
1560816000, 1560902400, 1560988800, 1561075200, 1561161600, 1561248000, 
1561334400, 1561420800, 1561507200, 1561593600, 1561680000, 1561766400, 
1561852800, 1561939200, 1562025600, 1562112000, 1562198400, 1562284800, 
1562371200, 1562457600, 1562544000, 1562630400, 1562716800, 1562803200, 
1562889600, 1562976000, 1563062400, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600, 
1563408000, 1563494400, 1563580800, 1563667200, 1563753600, 1563840000, 
1563926400, 1564012800, 1564099200, 1564185600, 1564272000, 1564358400, 
1564444800, 1564531200, 1564617600, 1564704000, 1564790400, 1564876800, 
1564963200, 1565049600, 1565136000, 1565222400, 1565308800, 1565395200, 
1565481600, 1565568000, 1565654400, 1565740800, 1565827200, 1565913600, 
1.566e+09, 1566086400, 1566172800, 1566259200, 1566345600, 1566432000, 
1566518400, 1566604800, 1566691200, 1566777600, 1566864000, 1566950400, 
1567036800, 1567123200, 1567209600, 1567296000, 1567382400, 1567468800, 
1567555200, 1567641600, 1567728000, 1567814400, 1567900800, 1567987200, 
1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 1568419200, 1568505600, 
1568592000, 1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569024000, 
1569110400, 1569196800, 1569283200, 1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 
1569628800, 1569715200, 1569801600, 1569888000, 1569974400, 1570060800, 
1570147200, 1570233600, 1570320000, 1570406400, 1570492800, 1570579200, 
1570665600, 1570752000, 1570838400, 1570924800, 1571011200, 1571097600, 
1571184000, 1571270400, 1571356800, 1571443200, 1571529600, 1571616000, 
1571702400, 1571788800, 1571875200, 1571961600, 1572048000, 1572134400, 
1572220800, 1572307200, 1572393600, 1572480000, 1572566400, 1572652800, 
1572739200, 1572825600, 1572912000, 1572998400, 1573084800, 1573171200, 
1573257600, 1573344000, 1573430400, 1573516800, 1573603200, 1573689600, 
1573776000, 1573862400, 1573948800, 1574035200, 1574121600, 1574208000, 
1574294400, 1574380800, 1574467200, 1574553600, 1574640000, 1574726400, 
1574812800, 1574899200, 1574985600, 1575072000, 1575158400, 1575244800, 
1575331200, 1575417600, 1575504000, 1575590400, 1575676800, 1575763200, 
1575849600, 1575936000, 1576022400, 1576108800, 1576195200, 1576281600, 
1576368000, 1576454400, 1576540800, 1576627200, 1576713600, 1576800000, 
1576886400, 1576972800, 1577059200, 1577145600, 1577232000, 1577318400, 
1577404800, 1577491200, 1577577600, 1577664000, 1577750400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), adm = c(1L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 13L, 
8L, 3L, 5L, 13L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 
7L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
3L, 4L, 13L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 5L, 
2L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
18L, 14L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 
5L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 12L, 
13L, 9L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 3L, 24L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 10L, 
6L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 17L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 2L, 
14L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 15L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 
11L, 3L, 5L, 14L, 7L, 3L, 20L, 17L, 14L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 4L, 
9L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 7L, 18L, 13L, 18L, 20L, 16L, 9L, 5L, 
13L, 16L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 21L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 
13L, 19L, 17L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 18L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 16L, 13L, 9L, 14L, 
8L, 20L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 8L, 16L, 10L, 9L, 20L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 16L, 
11L, 10L, 12L, 20L, 5L, 2L, 21L, 16L, 18L, 0L, 16L, 4L, 6L, 16L, 
6L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 22L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 7L, 9L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 12L, 6L, 20L, 10L, 17L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 9L, 13L, 
15L, 18L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 20L, 
16L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 10L, 8L, 17L, 24L, 8L, 15L, 16L, 9L, 10L, 
22L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 16L, 7L, 12L, 10L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 16L, 
13L, 4L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 11L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 19L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 
9L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 
2L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 4L, 
7L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 11L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 
11L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 
12L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 17L, 
15L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 16L, 17L, 6L, 
6L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 6L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 14L, 2L, 17L, 4L, 10L, 
6L, 1L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 6L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 
7L, 14L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 6L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 3L, 
8L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
6L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 
2L, 0L, 6L, 10L, 0L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
3L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
9L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 27L, 8L, 
12L, 20L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 10L, 
14L, 14L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 23L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 
10L, 8L, 13L, 16L, 10L, 11L, 18L, 7L, 15L, 18L, 10L, 9L, 15L, 
4L, 3L, 9L, 12L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 
15L, 7L, 7L, 14L, 15L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 22L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 12L, 
7L, 11L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 16L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 
14L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 
12L, 7L, 13L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
11L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 
7L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 
5L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 
3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 
5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 11L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
11L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 14L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 
2L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 
6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 
6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 20L, 8L, 10L, 7L, 
5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 17L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-1304L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to do a time series analysis with it.
I transformed it into a `ts` to get a `pacf`

```
ts1 <- zoo(df$adm, df$date)
ts <- as.xts(ts1)
pacf(ts)
```

The problem is that the x-axis, usually showing lags like, `1,2,3...`is showing lags in magnitudes of hundred of thousands.
[image]

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is closely related to this question: [Set frequency in xts object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744218/set-frequency-in-xts-object). The `frequency` is used in `pacf` [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/79298c499218846d14500255efd622b5021c10ec/src/library/stats/R/acf.R#L70).

In particular, in your case the frequency (time in days between observations) is really small:

```
> frequency(ts)
[1] 1.157407e-05
```

You have daily data, so if you set `attr(ts, 'frequency') <- 1` before `pacf` call, it will work.

```
ts1 <- zoo(df$adm, df$date)
ts <- xts::as.xts(ts1)
attr(ts, 'frequency') <- 1

pacf(ts)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** The `pacf()` function converts its main argument to `ts` by calling `as.ts()` and then computes the PACF from that. In your application you probably just want to treat the observations as an equidistant series so it's easiest to strip the time index and just compute the PACF of the data vector. You can do that via:

```
pacf(coredata(ts1))
pacf(coredata(ts))
```

Both lead to identical results.

**Details:** The `as.ts()` methods for both `zoo` and `xts` try to preserve the time index when creating the `ts` object. While the `zoo` method does not assume any knowledge about the time class and just converts it to numeric, the `xts` method behaves somewhat differently because it "understands" what a `POSIXct` object is.

In either case the time index gets coerced to numeric which is the time in seconds since 1970-01-01 for `POSIXct`. Therefore the distance between the observations is 1 day = 86400 seconds and hence the frequency is 1/86400 = 1.157407e-05. Using the simple `Date` class instead of `POSIXct` would avoid this problem.

Finally, `pacf(ts1)` fails because `as.ts(ts1)` creates a `ts` series with one missing value because there is one gap in the data:

```
ts1[221:224]
## 2017-01-11 2017-01-12 2017-01-14 2017-01-15 
##         15         15         10          8
```

Possibly it may be sensible to fill the observation for 2017-01-13 with 0?

Comment: Thank you, @Achim Zeileis; your answer makes me understand better my problem

Comment: So a key difference between `as.ts.zoo` and `as.ts.xts` are that the `as.ts.zoo` gives a series of length n+1 with the missing time being generated and an NA used as the corresponding value.  In contrast `as.ts.xts` gives a series of length n using the frequency but otherwise ignoring the times starting at a time of 1.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [fpp3 forecasting packages](https://otexts.com/fpp3/) I get the daily PACF lags per below if that helps.

(I don't use zoo/xts myself so can't say why that's showing the larger magnitudes.)

```r
library(fpp3)

df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(
  1465084800, 1465171200, 1465257600,
  1465344000, 1465430400, 1465516800, 1465603200, 1465689600, 1465776000,
  1465862400, 1465948800, 1466035200, 1466121600, 1466208000, 1466294400,
  1466380800, 1466467200, 1466553600, 1466640000, 1466726400, 1466812800,
  1466899200, 1466985600, 1467072000, 1467158400, 1467244800, 1467331200,
  1467417600, 1467504000, 1467590400, 1467676800, 1467763200, 1467849600,
  1467936000, 1468022400, 1468108800, 1468195200, 1468281600, 1468368000,
  1468454400, 1468540800, 1468627200, 1468713600, 1468800000, 1468886400,
  1468972800, 1469059200, 1469145600, 1469232000, 1469318400, 1469404800,
  1469491200, 1469577600, 1469664000, 1469750400, 1469836800, 1469923200,
  1470009600, 1470096000, 1470182400, 1470268800, 1470355200, 1470441600,
  1470528000, 1470614400, 1470700800, 1470787200, 1470873600, 1470960000,
  1471046400, 1471132800, 1471219200, 1471305600, 1471392000, 1471478400,
  1471564800, 1471651200, 1471737600, 1471824000, 1471910400, 1471996800,
  1472083200, 1472169600, 1472256000, 1472342400, 1472428800, 1472515200,
  1472601600, 1472688000, 1472774400, 1472860800, 1472947200, 1473033600,
  1473120000, 1473206400, 1473292800, 1473379200, 1473465600, 1473552000,
  1473638400, 1473724800, 1473811200, 1473897600, 1473984000, 1474070400,
  1474156800, 1474243200, 1474329600, 1474416000, 1474502400, 1474588800,
  1474675200, 1474761600, 1474848000, 1474934400, 1475020800, 1475107200,
  1475193600, 1475280000, 1475366400, 1475452800, 1475539200, 1475625600,
  1475712000, 1475798400, 1475884800, 1475971200, 1476057600, 1476144000,
  1476230400, 1476316800, 1476403200, 1476489600, 1476576000, 1476662400,
  1476748800, 1476835200, 1476921600, 1477008000, 1477094400, 1477180800,
  1477267200, 1477353600, 1477440000, 1477526400, 1477612800, 1477699200,
  1477785600, 1477872000, 1477958400, 1478044800, 1478131200, 1478217600,
  1478304000, 1478390400, 1478476800, 1478563200, 1478649600, 1478736000,
  1478822400, 1478908800, 1478995200, 1479081600, 1479168000, 1479254400,
  1479340800, 1479427200, 1479513600, 1479600000, 1479686400, 1479772800,
  1479859200, 1479945600, 1480032000, 1480118400, 1480204800, 1480291200,
  1480377600, 1480464000, 1480550400, 1480636800, 1480723200, 1480809600,
  1480896000, 1480982400, 1481068800, 1481155200, 1481241600, 1481328000,
  1481414400, 1481500800, 1481587200, 1481673600, 1481760000, 1481846400,
  1481932800, 1482019200, 1482105600, 1482192000, 1482278400, 1482364800,
  1482451200, 1482537600, 1482624000, 1482710400, 1482796800, 1482883200,
  1482969600, 1483056000, 1483142400, 1483228800, 1483315200, 1483401600,
  1483488000, 1483574400, 1483660800, 1483747200, 1483833600, 1483920000,
  1484006400, 1484092800, 1484179200, 1484352000, 1484438400, 1484524800,
  1484611200, 1484697600, 1484784000, 1484870400, 1484956800, 1485043200,
  1485129600, 1485216000, 1485302400, 1485388800, 1485475200, 1485561600,
  1485648000, 1485734400, 1485820800, 1485907200, 1485993600, 1486080000,
  1486166400, 1486252800, 1486339200, 1486425600, 1486512000, 1486598400,
  1486684800, 1486771200, 1486857600, 1486944000, 1487030400, 1487116800,
  1487203200, 1487289600, 1487376000, 1487462400, 1487548800, 1487635200,
  1487721600, 1487808000, 1487894400, 1487980800, 1488067200, 1488153600,
  1488240000, 1488326400, 1488412800, 1488499200, 1488585600, 1488672000,
  1488758400, 1488844800, 1488931200, 1489017600, 1489104000, 1489190400,
  1489276800, 1489363200, 1489449600, 1489536000, 1489622400, 1489708800,
  1489795200, 1489881600, 1489968000, 1490054400, 1490140800, 1490227200,
  1490313600, 1490400000, 1490486400, 1490572800, 1490659200, 1490745600,
  1490832000, 1490918400, 1491004800, 1491091200, 1491177600, 1491264000,
  1491350400, 1491436800, 1491523200, 1491609600, 1491696000, 1491782400,
  1491868800, 1491955200, 1492041600, 1492128000, 1492214400, 1492300800,
  1492387200, 1492473600, 1492560000, 1492646400, 1492732800, 1492819200,
  1492905600, 1492992000, 1493078400, 1493164800, 1493251200, 1493337600,
  1493424000, 1493510400, 1493596800, 1493683200, 1493769600, 1493856000,
  1493942400, 1494028800, 1494115200, 1494201600, 1494288000, 1494374400,
  1494460800, 1494547200, 1494633600, 1494720000, 1494806400, 1494892800,
  1494979200, 1495065600, 1495152000, 1495238400, 1495324800, 1495411200,
  1495497600, 1495584000, 1495670400, 1495756800, 1495843200, 1495929600,
  1496016000, 1496102400, 1496188800, 1496275200, 1496361600, 1496448000,
  1496534400, 1496620800, 1496707200, 1496793600, 1496880000, 1496966400,
  1497052800, 1497139200, 1497225600, 1497312000, 1497398400, 1497484800,
  1497571200, 1497657600, 1497744000, 1497830400, 1497916800, 1498003200,
  1498089600, 1498176000, 1498262400, 1498348800, 1498435200, 1498521600,
  1498608000, 1498694400, 1498780800, 1498867200, 1498953600, 1499040000,
  1499126400, 1499212800, 1499299200, 1499385600, 1499472000, 1499558400,
  1499644800, 1499731200, 1499817600, 1499904000, 1499990400, 1500076800,
  1500163200, 1500249600, 1500336000, 1500422400, 1500508800, 1500595200,
  1500681600, 1500768000, 1500854400, 1500940800, 1501027200, 1501113600,
  1501200000, 1501286400, 1501372800, 1501459200, 1501545600, 1501632000,
  1501718400, 1501804800, 1501891200, 1501977600, 1502064000, 1502150400,
  1502236800, 1502323200, 1502409600, 1502496000, 1502582400, 1502668800,
  1502755200, 1502841600, 1502928000, 1503014400, 1503100800, 1503187200,
  1503273600, 1503360000, 1503446400, 1503532800, 1503619200, 1503705600,
  1503792000, 1503878400, 1503964800, 1504051200, 1504137600, 1504224000,
  1504310400, 1504396800, 1504483200, 1504569600, 1504656000, 1504742400,
  1504828800, 1504915200, 1505001600, 1505088000, 1505174400, 1505260800,
  1505347200, 1505433600, 1505520000, 1505606400, 1505692800, 1505779200,
  1505865600, 1505952000, 1506038400, 1506124800, 1506211200, 1506297600,
  1506384000, 1506470400, 1506556800, 1506643200, 1506729600, 1506816000,
  1506902400, 1506988800, 1507075200, 1507161600, 1507248000, 1507334400,
  1507420800, 1507507200, 1507593600, 1507680000, 1507766400, 1507852800,
  1507939200, 1508025600, 1508112000, 1508198400, 1508284800, 1508371200,
  1508457600, 1508544000, 1508630400, 1508716800, 1508803200, 1508889600,
  1508976000, 1509062400, 1509148800, 1509235200, 1509321600, 1509408000,
  1509494400, 1509580800, 1509667200, 1509753600, 1509840000, 1509926400,
  1510012800, 1510099200, 1510185600, 1510272000, 1510358400, 1510444800,
  1510531200, 1510617600, 1510704000, 1510790400, 1510876800, 1510963200,
  1511049600, 1511136000, 1511222400, 1511308800, 1511395200, 1511481600,
  1511568000, 1511654400, 1511740800, 1511827200, 1511913600, 1.512e+09,
  1512086400, 1512172800, 1512259200, 1512345600, 1512432000, 1512518400,
  1512604800, 1512691200, 1512777600, 1512864000, 1512950400, 1513036800,
  1513123200, 1513209600, 1513296000, 1513382400, 1513468800, 1513555200,
  1513641600, 1513728000, 1513814400, 1513900800, 1513987200, 1514073600,
  1514160000, 1514246400, 1514332800, 1514419200, 1514505600, 1514592000,
  1514678400, 1514764800, 1514851200, 1514937600, 1515024000, 1515110400,
  1515196800, 1515283200, 1515369600, 1515456000, 1515542400, 1515628800,
  1515715200, 1515801600, 1515888000, 1515974400, 1516060800, 1516147200,
  1516233600, 1516320000, 1516406400, 1516492800, 1516579200, 1516665600,
  1516752000, 1516838400, 1516924800, 1517011200, 1517097600, 1517184000,
  1517270400, 1517356800, 1517443200, 1517529600, 1517616000, 1517702400,
  1517788800, 1517875200, 1517961600, 1518048000, 1518134400, 1518220800,
  1518307200, 1518393600, 1518480000, 1518566400, 1518652800, 1518739200,
  1518825600, 1518912000, 1518998400, 1519084800, 1519171200, 1519257600,
  1519344000, 1519430400, 1519516800, 1519603200, 1519689600, 1519776000,
  1519862400, 1519948800, 1520035200, 1520121600, 1520208000, 1520294400,
  1520380800, 1520467200, 1520553600, 1520640000, 1520726400, 1520812800,
  1520899200, 1520985600, 1521072000, 1521158400, 1521244800, 1521331200,
  1521417600, 1521504000, 1521590400, 1521676800, 1521763200, 1521849600,
  1521936000, 1522022400, 1522108800, 1522195200, 1522281600, 1522368000,
  1522454400, 1522540800, 1522627200, 1522713600, 1522800000, 1522886400,
  1522972800, 1523059200, 1523145600, 1523232000, 1523318400, 1523404800,
  1523491200, 1523577600, 1523664000, 1523750400, 1523836800, 1523923200,
  1524009600, 1524096000, 1524182400, 1524268800, 1524355200, 1524441600,
  1524528000, 1524614400, 1524700800, 1524787200, 1524873600, 1524960000,
  1525046400, 1525132800, 1525219200, 1525305600, 1525392000, 1525478400,
  1525564800, 1525651200, 1525737600, 1525824000, 1525910400, 1525996800,
  1526083200, 1526169600, 1526256000, 1526342400, 1526428800, 1526515200,
  1526601600, 1526688000, 1526774400, 1526860800, 1526947200, 1527033600,
  1527120000, 1527206400, 1527292800, 1527379200, 1527465600, 1527552000,
  1527638400, 1527724800, 1527811200, 1527897600, 1527984000, 1528070400,
  1528156800, 1528243200, 1528329600, 1528416000, 1528502400, 1528588800,
  1528675200, 1528761600, 1528848000, 1528934400, 1529020800, 1529107200,
  1529193600, 1529280000, 1529366400, 1529452800, 1529539200, 1529625600,
  1529712000, 1529798400, 1529884800, 1529971200, 1530057600, 1530144000,
  1530230400, 1530316800, 1530403200, 1530489600, 1530576000, 1530662400,
  1530748800, 1530835200, 1530921600, 1531008000, 1531094400, 1531180800,
  1531267200, 1531353600, 1531440000, 1531526400, 1531612800, 1531699200,
  1531785600, 1531872000, 1531958400, 1532044800, 1532131200, 1532217600,
  1532304000, 1532390400, 1532476800, 1532563200, 1532649600, 1532736000,
  1532822400, 1532908800, 1532995200, 1533081600, 1533168000, 1533254400,
  1533340800, 1533427200, 1533513600, 1533600000, 1533686400, 1533772800,
  1533859200, 1533945600, 1534032000, 1534118400, 1534204800, 1534291200,
  1534377600, 1534464000, 1534550400, 1534636800, 1534723200, 1534809600,
  1534896000, 1534982400, 1535068800, 1535155200, 1535241600, 1535328000,
  1535414400, 1535500800, 1535587200, 1535673600, 1535760000, 1535846400,
  1535932800, 1536019200, 1536105600, 1536192000, 1536278400, 1536364800,
  1536451200, 1536537600, 1536624000, 1536710400, 1536796800, 1536883200,
  1536969600, 1537056000, 1537142400, 1537228800, 1537315200, 1537401600,
  1537488000, 1537574400, 1537660800, 1537747200, 1537833600, 1537920000,
  1538006400, 1538092800, 1538179200, 1538265600, 1538352000, 1538438400,
  1538524800, 1538611200, 1538697600, 1538784000, 1538870400, 1538956800,
  1539043200, 1539129600, 1539216000, 1539302400, 1539388800, 1539475200,
  1539561600, 1539648000, 1539734400, 1539820800, 1539907200, 1539993600,
  1540080000, 1540166400, 1540252800, 1540339200, 1540425600, 1540512000,
  1540598400, 1540684800, 1540771200, 1540857600, 1540944000, 1541030400,
  1541116800, 1541203200, 1541289600, 1541376000, 1541462400, 1541548800,
  1541635200, 1541721600, 1541808000, 1541894400, 1541980800, 1542067200,
  1542153600, 1542240000, 1542326400, 1542412800, 1542499200, 1542585600,
  1542672000, 1542758400, 1542844800, 1542931200, 1543017600, 1543104000,
  1543190400, 1543276800, 1543363200, 1543449600, 1543536000, 1543622400,
  1543708800, 1543795200, 1543881600, 1543968000, 1544054400, 1544140800,
  1544227200, 1544313600, 1544400000, 1544486400, 1544572800, 1544659200,
  1544745600, 1544832000, 1544918400, 1545004800, 1545091200, 1545177600,
  1545264000, 1545350400, 1545436800, 1545523200, 1545609600, 1545696000,
  1545782400, 1545868800, 1545955200, 1546041600, 1546128000, 1546214400,
  1546300800, 1546387200, 1546473600, 1546560000, 1546646400, 1546732800,
  1546819200, 1546905600, 1546992000, 1547078400, 1547164800, 1547251200,
  1547337600, 1547424000, 1547510400, 1547596800, 1547683200, 1547769600,
  1547856000, 1547942400, 1548028800, 1548115200, 1548201600, 1548288000,
  1548374400, 1548460800, 1548547200, 1548633600, 1548720000, 1548806400,
  1548892800, 1548979200, 1549065600, 1549152000, 1549238400, 1549324800,
  1549411200, 1549497600, 1549584000, 1549670400, 1549756800, 1549843200,
  1549929600, 1550016000, 1550102400, 1550188800, 1550275200, 1550361600,
  1550448000, 1550534400, 1550620800, 1550707200, 1550793600, 1550880000,
  1550966400, 1551052800, 1551139200, 1551225600, 1551312000, 1551398400,
  1551484800, 1551571200, 1551657600, 1551744000, 1551830400, 1551916800,
  1552003200, 1552089600, 1552176000, 1552262400, 1552348800, 1552435200,
  1552521600, 1552608000, 1552694400, 1552780800, 1552867200, 1552953600,
  1553040000, 1553126400, 1553212800, 1553299200, 1553385600, 1553472000,
  1553558400, 1553644800, 1553731200, 1553817600, 1553904000, 1553990400,
  1554076800, 1554163200, 1554249600, 1554336000, 1554422400, 1554508800,
  1554595200, 1554681600, 1554768000, 1554854400, 1554940800, 1555027200,
  1555113600, 1555200000, 1555286400, 1555372800, 1555459200, 1555545600,
  1555632000, 1555718400, 1555804800, 1555891200, 1555977600, 1556064000,
  1556150400, 1556236800, 1556323200, 1556409600, 1556496000, 1556582400,
  1556668800, 1556755200, 1556841600, 1556928000, 1557014400, 1557100800,
  1557187200, 1557273600, 1557360000, 1557446400, 1557532800, 1557619200,
  1557705600, 1557792000, 1557878400, 1557964800, 1558051200, 1558137600,
  1558224000, 1558310400, 1558396800, 1558483200, 1558569600, 1558656000,
  1558742400, 1558828800, 1558915200, 1559001600, 1559088000, 1559174400,
  1559260800, 1559347200, 1559433600, 1559520000, 1559606400, 1559692800,
  1559779200, 1559865600, 1559952000, 1560038400, 1560124800, 1560211200,
  1560297600, 1560384000, 1560470400, 1560556800, 1560643200, 1560729600,
  1560816000, 1560902400, 1560988800, 1561075200, 1561161600, 1561248000,
  1561334400, 1561420800, 1561507200, 1561593600, 1561680000, 1561766400,
  1561852800, 1561939200, 1562025600, 1562112000, 1562198400, 1562284800,
  1562371200, 1562457600, 1562544000, 1562630400, 1562716800, 1562803200,
  1562889600, 1562976000, 1563062400, 1563148800, 1563235200, 1563321600,
  1563408000, 1563494400, 1563580800, 1563667200, 1563753600, 1563840000,
  1563926400, 1564012800, 1564099200, 1564185600, 1564272000, 1564358400,
  1564444800, 1564531200, 1564617600, 1564704000, 1564790400, 1564876800,
  1564963200, 1565049600, 1565136000, 1565222400, 1565308800, 1565395200,
  1565481600, 1565568000, 1565654400, 1565740800, 1565827200, 1565913600,
  1.566e+09, 1566086400, 1566172800, 1566259200, 1566345600, 1566432000,
  1566518400, 1566604800, 1566691200, 1566777600, 1566864000, 1566950400,
  1567036800, 1567123200, 1567209600, 1567296000, 1567382400, 1567468800,
  1567555200, 1567641600, 1567728000, 1567814400, 1567900800, 1567987200,
  1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 1568419200, 1568505600,
  1568592000, 1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569024000,
  1569110400, 1569196800, 1569283200, 1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400,
  1569628800, 1569715200, 1569801600, 1569888000, 1569974400, 1570060800,
  1570147200, 1570233600, 1570320000, 1570406400, 1570492800, 1570579200,
  1570665600, 1570752000, 1570838400, 1570924800, 1571011200, 1571097600,
  1571184000, 1571270400, 1571356800, 1571443200, 1571529600, 1571616000,
  1571702400, 1571788800, 1571875200, 1571961600, 1572048000, 1572134400,
  1572220800, 1572307200, 1572393600, 1572480000, 1572566400, 1572652800,
  1572739200, 1572825600, 1572912000, 1572998400, 1573084800, 1573171200,
  1573257600, 1573344000, 1573430400, 1573516800, 1573603200, 1573689600,
  1573776000, 1573862400, 1573948800, 1574035200, 1574121600, 1574208000,
  1574294400, 1574380800, 1574467200, 1574553600, 1574640000, 1574726400,
  1574812800, 1574899200, 1574985600, 1575072000, 1575158400, 1575244800,
  1575331200, 1575417600, 1575504000, 1575590400, 1575676800, 1575763200,
  1575849600, 1575936000, 1576022400, 1576108800, 1576195200, 1576281600,
  1576368000, 1576454400, 1576540800, 1576627200, 1576713600, 1576800000,
  1576886400, 1576972800, 1577059200, 1577145600, 1577232000, 1577318400,
  1577404800, 1577491200, 1577577600, 1577664000, 1577750400
), class = c(
  "POSIXct",
  "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), adm = c(
  1L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 13L,
  8L, 3L, 5L, 13L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 10L, 10L, 7L,
  7L, 3L, 1L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L,
  3L, 4L, 13L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 5L,
  2L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 11L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 4L,
  18L, 14L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 7L,
  5L, 8L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 12L,
  13L, 9L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 3L, 24L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 10L,
  6L, 10L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 17L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 2L,
  14L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 15L, 9L, 7L, 3L, 9L,
  11L, 3L, 5L, 14L, 7L, 3L, 20L, 17L, 14L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 4L,
  9L, 5L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 7L, 18L, 13L, 18L, 20L, 16L, 9L, 5L,
  13L, 16L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 13L, 21L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 4L, 7L, 5L,
  13L, 19L, 17L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 18L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 16L, 13L, 9L, 14L,
  8L, 20L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 8L, 16L, 10L, 9L, 20L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 16L,
  11L, 10L, 12L, 20L, 5L, 2L, 21L, 16L, 18L, 0L, 16L, 4L, 6L, 16L,
  6L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 8L, 13L, 22L, 14L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 14L, 7L, 9L,
  7L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 12L, 6L, 20L, 10L, 17L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 9L, 13L,
  15L, 18L, 10L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 20L,
  16L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 10L, 8L, 17L, 24L, 8L, 15L, 16L, 9L, 10L,
  22L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 16L, 7L, 12L, 10L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 16L,
  13L, 4L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 11L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 19L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 4L,
  9L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 13L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 5L,
  2L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 12L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 4L,
  7L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 11L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 5L,
  3L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 9L, 9L,
  11L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 13L, 6L,
  12L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 11L, 17L,
  15L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 16L, 17L, 6L,
  6L, 9L, 6L, 12L, 6L, 13L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 14L, 2L, 17L, 4L, 10L,
  6L, 1L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 11L, 6L,
  9L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 11L, 7L, 6L,
  5L, 5L, 11L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 9L,
  7L, 14L, 10L, 4L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 6L, 5L, 12L, 5L, 3L,
  8L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 7L,
  6L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 9L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L,
  7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 0L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L,
  1L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 12L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 6L,
  5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 3L,
  2L, 0L, 6L, 10L, 0L, 8L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
  3L, 1L, 9L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 1L,
  2L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 0L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L,
  4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
  9L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
  0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,
  0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
  1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
  0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
  1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,
  1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L,
  1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 13L, 10L, 13L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 27L, 8L,
  12L, 20L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 13L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 10L,
  14L, 14L, 10L, 10L, 7L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 23L, 7L, 12L, 6L, 7L,
  10L, 8L, 13L, 16L, 10L, 11L, 18L, 7L, 15L, 18L, 10L, 9L, 15L,
  4L, 3L, 9L, 12L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 9L, 7L, 9L,
  15L, 7L, 7L, 14L, 15L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 22L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 12L,
  7L, 11L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 5L, 16L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 4L,
  14L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 11L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 8L,
  12L, 7L, 13L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 6L, 8L, 7L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L,
  11L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 6L,
  6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 9L,
  7L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L,
  3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 10L,
  5L, 4L, 0L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 7L,
  3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L,
  5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 3L,
  2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 11L,
  3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 3L,
  11L, 7L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 1L, 14L, 7L, 7L,
  7L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 7L,
  6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 9L, 7L,
  2L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L,
  6L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 7L,
  6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 11L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 20L, 8L, 10L, 7L,
  5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 17L, 6L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 1L
)), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -1304L
), class = "data.frame")


df |> 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) |> 
  tsibble(index = date) |> 
  fill_gaps() |> 
  PACF(adm) |> 
  autoplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem as below.

```
ts1 <- zoo(df$adm, df$date)
ts <- as.xts(ts1)

pl = pacf(ts, xaxt="n")
axis(1, pl$lag, seq_along(pl$lag))
```

[image]